# How to using the home variable instead of the system variable(linux)?

Tags: linux, emacs

There are two versions of Emacs on my linux system. Under the system directory , the emacs version is 23.1 which didn't support the `elpa`. So, I updated the emacs to 24.5 under the home directory, and export to the `PATH`. But when I call the emacs, it seems that it didn't use the newer version.

So, how to solve this? I want to use the newer version under the home directory instead of the older one.

Comment: It sounds like you've either made a mistake with `PATH`, or you're starting Emacs in a way which does not have access to whatever it is that you've done to update `PATH`. You haven't provided any details, so I can't make any suggestions.

Comment: I have put the `PATH` in the `.bash_profile` , and this is the code `PATH=$HOME/local/bin/`, `$HOME/local/bin/` is the emacs's directory.  When I change the name 'emacs' to 'Emacs' under this directory and call "Emacs", things get right. So, Whether the system's variable has shielded the home's variable name when they have the same variable name?

Comment: (a) What do you mean by "system's variable" and "home's variable"? (b) Did you *really* change `PATH` to be *only* `$HOME/local/bin/` ?!? (c) Are you exporting the modified `PATH` value? (d) It really sounds like you've set `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/local/bin` rather than `PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH` (as the former would not use your local `emacs` if it found another `emacs` earlier.

Comment: Yes, I have set `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/local/bin`. Thanks, I have solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to launch emacs in your home directory, you should put path of your own emacs before the path to system one, i.e, you should config your PATH environment variable as the following if you are using bash shell.

> export PATH=~/emacs:$PATH